# How to take out attribute from two ArrayList of object which have different match in optimize way

Tags: java, performance, array

I have two `ArrayList`s of objects and the after comparison I am taking out the value which has a difference based on the attribute.

So in my condition when the `deptCode` is the same in both lists but `deptName` is different then the output will be the updated `deptName`.

Here is my code.

```
public class educationMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<person> list=new ArrayList<person>();  
        person l1 = new person(1,"Samual",100,"Sales","Business");
        person l2 = new person(2,"Alex",100,"Sales","Business");
        person l3 = new person(3,"Bob",101,"Engineering","Technology");
        person l4 = new person(4,"Michel",101,"Engineering","Technology");
        person l5 = new person(5,"Ryan",102,"PR","Services");
        person l6 = new person(6,"Horward",103,"Leadership","Managmnet");
        person l7 = new person(7,"Cyna",104,"HR","Human Resource");
        list.add(l1);  
        list.add(l2);  
        list.add(l3); 
        list.add(l4);  
        list.add(l5);  
        list.add(l6); 
        list.add(l7); 
        
        List<department> depList = new ArrayList<department>();
        
         department d1 = new department(100, "Sales","Business");
         department d2 = new department(101, "Engineering","Technology");
         department d3 = new department(102, "PR","Support");
         depList.add(d1);  
         depList.add(d2);  
         depList.add(d3); 

         List<person> listC = new ArrayList<person>();
         
         
         // My comparision Logic
         for(person p : list) {
             boolean  flag = false;
             for (department d:depList) {
                 if(p.deptCode == d.deptCode) {
                     if(p.deptName != d.deptName) {
                         p.deptName = d.deptName;
                         listC.add(p);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         
         for(person b:listC){  
             System.out.println(b.personId+" "+b.name+" "+b.deptCode+" "+b.parentDept+" "+b.deptName); 
         }
    }

}
```

This is code is working fine and I am getting my output.

```
5 Ryan 102 PR Support
```

But instead of using two for loop do we have any efficient way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

### Code review:

- Capitalize class names
- Be consistent in formatting: `List<person> list=new ArrayList<person>()` doesn't have spaces around `=`, but in all other places it has. Also indentations are inconsistent.
- Variable naming: names should say what particular object is. `l1` doesn't say anything at all. Furthermore, if they are not used anywhere, you can omit variable declaration and add them to the list right away, like: `someList.add(new Person(...))`. `list` better be named as `personas` and `listC` as `personasWithMismatchedDepartmentName` to reflect their actual content.
- `flag` inside loop is not used anywhere, should be deleted
- Comments like `// My comparision Logic` doesn't bring any value to the reader, better if this logic will be in a separate method.
- Try to reduce amount of nested conditions. Instead of

```
if(p.deptCode == d.deptCode) {
  if(p.deptName != d.deptName) { ... }
```

better write

```
if(p.deptCode == d.deptCode && p.deptName != d.deptName) {...}
```

### Algo impovement:

Your algo has `O(number of personas) * O(number of departments)` time complexity. You can reduce that to `O(number of personas)` if you replace inner loop with hash table lookup.

We can create hash map from department code to department and instead of iterating over all departments in inner loop, we can lookup required department by its code. Pseudocode:

```
for (dept in departments):
  add mapping (deptCode, dept) to hashmap

for (p in personas):
  dept = hashmap.get(p.deptCode)
  if p.deptName != dept.name:
    p.deptName = dept.name
    add p to list
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site!
I doubt that there are much better ways to do what you want to do here. You'll always have to compare each element of `list` to each of `depList`. Databases have to do similar things like this; you could try resarching in that direction (index, ...), but for small projects this is fine.
**Ideally, you'd want to setup your data in a way where problems like this can't occur**, this would mean removing the department info from the persons and only keeping the department ID.

On a sidenote, classes (`educationMain`, `person`, `department`) always start with a capital letter by convention. You're also missing some whitespace, but that's easily fixed with an autoformatter. The `flag` inside the outer loop also serves no purpose.